# If $R$ is Noetherian, show $R\ncong R[x]$ as rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have a problem. In my exam, there is a question.

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ be a finitely generated R-module. The (a) part requires me to prove that if $\phi:M\to M$ is surjective, it is bijective.

I can't prove the (b) part: prove $R$ could not be isomorphic to $R[x]$ as rings. Honestly I don't think the (a) part would help, I say it just in case. Anyone can prove this?

Comment: I hope the question is about part b) only. The answer to part a) exists in several questions on the site already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is an isomorphism $R \cong R[x]$. Compose this with the quotient map to get $R \cong R[x] \to R$, which is surjective. By part (a) we know that this composition must be bijective. However, we know that $R[x] \to R$ has a kernel generated by $x \neq 0$, which is a contradiction.

I believe there is a subtlelty though in the fact that the map $R \to R$ may not be an $R$-module homomorphism, since we don't know that the isomorphism $R \cong R[x]$ is an isomorphism of $R$-algebras. However, just give the $R$ on the left the $R$-module structure coming from the isomorphism $R[x] \cong R$ and then part (a) will apply - observe $R$ is noetherian with this new module structure since $R[x]$ is.

Alternatively, use the proof of part (a) to prove the same statement for a *ring* map $R \to R$ of noetherian rings.